# How to edit html section Real Time with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have Category list sidebar and I want to make it sortable up and down, also remove one list of them with bottom.
Here is image:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgKiF.png)

**HTML CODE:**

```
 <div class="side-nav-categories">
    <div class="title"><strong>Category</strong></div>
    <ul id="category-tabs">
        <li><a href="javascript:void" class="main-category"> Web Applications<i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
            <ul class="sub-category-tabs">
                <li><a href="javascript:void">HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void">SCSS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="category-tabs">
        <li><a href="javascript:void" class="main-category">Script<i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
            <ul class="sub-category-tabs">
                <li><a href="javascript:void">Javascript</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void">jQuery</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void">Angular JS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="category-tabs">
        <li><a href="javascript:void" class="main-category">Server Script<i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
            <ul class="sub-category-tabs">
                <li><a href="javascript:void">C#</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void">PHP</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void">ASP.Net</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: What have  you tried? What exact problem are  you having?

Comment: It would be great if you could upvote my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the element from its id:

```js
document.getElementById(**yourId**).innerHTML = 'Realtime';
```

The above line just changed the value inside an element in realtime, using JavaScript. Keep in mind though, that you don't need to use `innerHTML`, you can use any JavaScript attribute that you want.